# Maya Python command for get selected anim layers

Tags: python, maya, mel

I'm trying to query what animation layers are selected using Python.

MEL works fine:

```
treeView -query -selectItem ("AnimLayerTabanimLayerEditor")
```

However a similar Python command returns an error:

```
cmds.treeView(q=True, selectItem=[True, "AnimLayerTabanimLayerEditor"])
```

Error:

```
// Error: TypeError: file <maya console> line 1: Flag 'selectItem' must be passed a boolean argument when query flag is set //
```

The weird part is that selectItem asks for 2 arguments: a string, then a boolean (I've tried it in that order too). The MEL command works without a boolean (tried that in Python too).

Comment: Try passing a tuple instead of a list for `selectItem`: `cmds.treeView(q=True, selectItem=(True, "AnimLayerTabanimLayerEditor"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to invert the order: in python the first argument is the target of the command, and the keywords come after; in Mel the flags come first.

If you're querying you just want the `query` and `selectItem` flags both true in Python:

```
 selected = cmds.treeView (mytreeview, q=True, selectItem=True)
```

and setting looks like:

```
 cmds.treeView(mytreeview, e=True, selectItem = ('thingToSelect', True))
```